# How do I set page label for a single page in iText7?

Tags: java, itext, itext7

In `iText` page labels can be set the following way:

```
PdfPage page = pdfDoc.getPage(1);

page.setPageLabel(PageLabelNumberingStyle.UPPERCASE_ROMAN_NUMERALS, "Cover", 1);
```

However, the resulting PDF will have its first page labelled `CoverI` and all the following pages will also be labelled. I don't want anything added to my page label `Cover` nor any other page labelled.

So, **how do I set page label for a single page?**

I'd like the first page to have a custom string label, other pages arabic numerals, and the following pages roman numerals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page label configuration applies to the page you set it to and to all the consecutive pages. So to make the page 2 and on have the standard Arabic numerals, just make sure that configuration is set explicitly. For the case you mentioned the code would look roughly as follows:

```
PdfPage page = pdfDocument.getPage(1);
page.setPageLabel(PageLabelNumberingStyle.UPPERCASE_ROMAN_NUMERALS, "Cover", 1);

page = pdfDocument.getPage(2);
int pageNumToStartFrom = 2; // Replace it with 1 if you want the blocks to be numbered independently
page.setPageLabel(PageLabelNumberingStyle.DECIMAL_ARABIC_NUMERALS, null, pageNumToStartFrom);

page = pdfDocument.getPage(4);
pageNumToStartFrom = 4; // Replace it with 1 if you want the blocks to be numbered independently
page.setPageLabel(PageLabelNumberingStyle.UPPERCASE_ROMAN_NUMERALS, null, pageNumToStartFrom);
```

Comment: Thanks. I only needed one thing to make your answer right for my use case: `page.setPageLabel(null, "Cover")` creates label  `Cover` without any prefix.